# What is the best Image resizer with high quality and aspect ratio (like telegram or whatsapp or... )?

Tags: android

I want resize image without loosing quality and aspect ratio and use this code :

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/download/0.jpg";

BitmapFactory.Options Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Options.inSampleSize = 4;
Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, Options);

int newWidht = 600;
int originalWidth = Options.outWidth;
int originalHeight = Options.outHeight;
float AspectRatio = (float)originalWidth / originalHeight;
float tempnewHeight = newWidht/ AspectRatio;
int  newHeight = (int)tempnewHeight;

Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidth, newHeight, false);

ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File mypath=new File("/sdcard/download/","1.jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = null;

fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

But this method reduce quality or cant good work for deference resolution and My saved pic is very bad and hatch.
i see some post about this and cant find solution.
I think Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() reduce quality

Please help me
thankyou

Comment: You're passing `false` as the `filter` parameter to `createScaledBitmap`. This probably leads to nearest-neighbor scaling, which often looks pretty bad.

Comment: @Michael i test true and false but nothing change

Comment: There should definitely be a difference in most cases, since (judging by the `Bitmap` source code) it either uses nearest-neighbor scaling or bilinear filtering based on the `filter` parameter. Whether bilinear filtering is good enough for you is up to you to decide. If it isn't you may have to look for some alternative scaling solution (e.g. some 3rd party library).

Comment: @Michael say its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best quality and smaller size.
 
this line is answer

```
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
```

Comment: Very Gooooooooooooooood Answer. thankyou. nobody help me exept you. very thax